# Minimal polynomial and diagonalization.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

How would I be able to prove that a linear endomorphism $T$ is not diagonalizable if it's minimal polynomial is $x^2(x-1)(x+1)$?

I thought I could try to put this into Jordan blocks and say that since $2$ is the maximum value of the eigenvalue of $0$, then the characteristic polynomial for $T$ will have an exponent value equal to or greater than $2$ for the eigenvalue of $0$. So the eigenvalues are not distinct and therefore it is not diagonalizable.

But then for $1$ and $-1$ it could also mean that the characteristic polynomial has an exponent greater than or equal to $1$ and this doesn't really seem like a concrete proof at all to me. So I was just wondering of a better way I should prove this. Thanks.

Comment: The point is really that you have an $x^2$ rather than an $x$, which affects the structure you 0 Jordan block can have.

Comment: Eigenvalues don't have to be distinct in order to be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What does it mean if the minimal polynomial contains a factor of $x^2$ instead of $x$?

Alternate Hint: Show that if $T$ is diagonalizable then all distinct factors of the minimal polynomial appear with exponent of $1$, e.g. no squares like $x^2$. (Using the diagonalization)

Comment: So if instead of $x^2(x-1)(x+1)$ as the minimal polynomial, it was just $(x-1)(x+1)$ would this mean that it is now diagonalizable?

Comment: @SofiaJune Yes that is true, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29#Applications . If $T$ is an endomorphism then it is diagonalizable if and only if all terms of the factorized minimal polynomial are distinct, i.e. no repeated roots.